# Basic Java Web App From Bitbucket to Heroku Procfile Issue

Tags: java, git, heroku, bitbucket, procfile

I am just trying to learn how bitbucket and heroku works together. I created basic maven web app in java which includes just index.jsp page "hello world" in it. Then turned into git repo and push to bitbucket and heroku. The problem is when i open project on heroku "Application error" is shown on page. when i look into logs on heroku, i saw that there is a problem with procfile. I dont know how to adjust procfile, i just search on web and take it from there to my project.

Could you please tell me how to modify this procfile regarding to my maven web project?

The project structure below;

Procfile file has=>  web: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/*

[My Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gySN6.png)

Given error on logs below,

[Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcH3L.png)

Pom.Xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>exampleProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>exampleProject</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>exampleProject Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>exampleProject</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: run `heroku logs` and paste the error message here. Looks like your `Procfile` command is missing a main class name.

Comment: @codefinger I added as a picture.